# Подключить rfunc.dll в firebird 2.5 / win64

Tags: firebird

Есть программа под windows.
Она использует firebird  в качестве базы данных.

Firebird запускается локально (доступен только из exe файла, насколько я понимаю)

И в качестве хранения данных использует файл с расширением .fdb

Мне удалось установить firebird 2.5 и подключиться к файлу .fdb при помощи установленного firebird.

И я смог успешно получить все данные с файла.

Но есть одна таблица, в которой данные хранятся в виде зашифрованной строки.

Например: 
YslRru709fdHXjE3RFg4MGTOT67v4Oj1R0I/MEBGPjdx20my7Ovv+1pIKS9GWjw8edNsgdnH3ck=
YclRru309fdEXDE3R104M2fMT67u5ev8WFo6MEpJPD5uy0+v+eDt+UZaPDZDTD07ec1JqOfg6vRPWDwqSE07OFz4eYTX0NrP

Так же, я нашел процедуру, которая, я полагаю, связана с тем, что бы раскодировать эту строку.

Проблематика в том, что, когда я пытаюсь вызвать эту процедуру, то я получаю ошибку, function Z is undefined. 
Т.е. процедура вызывает функцию, которая не определена.

Я нашел файлы:
gds32.dll
rfunc.dll

Я полагаю, что исходники rfunc.dll лежат здесь: http://rfunc.sourceforge.net/rus/rfunc.htm

Я полагаю, что в этих файлах описаны требуемые функции.

Но я мне не удалось подключить эти файлы в свой новоустановленный firebird 2.5.
На все мои попытки добавления файлов в папку UDF, правки firebird.conf, я получаю ту же ошибку, что функция Z не определена.

Причиной, я думаю, может быть то, что rfunc.dll работает под win32  (В файле, во второй строке такой текст присутствует: This program must be run under Win32)

Вопрос, как мне эмулировать win32 или как мне конвертировать rfunc.dll для win64?

И ещё: если в папке UDF firebird нашел файл .dll, но по каким-то причинам не смог его подключить, об этом где-то логи найти можно?

Comment: По поводу ошибок подключения UDF в логах - нет, они не пишутся. В старых версиях логи вообще были очень скудные, а в новых (3.0 и выше) UDF признаны устаревшими. В 4.0 они вообще будут по умолчанию отключены.

Comment: «как мне конвертировать rfunc.dll для win64» - взять исходники и скомпилировать в свежей версии MS Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

На замену rFunc есть библиотека AUDFL (assembla.com/spaces/audfl_rfunc). Она полностью покрывает функции rfunc и есть под 64бит